# TypeError: this.state.userInfo.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, I'm kinda new to react ,why I'm not being able to map through the data.
I have tried a different couple of things but nothing has helped.
Maybe the reason is that it's an object.
Can any one help?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Profile.css";

import ProfileCard from "../ProfileCard/ProfileCard";

class Profile extends Component {
  state = {
    userInfo: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const {  id } = this.props.match.params;
    axios
      .get(`/api/user/info/${id}`)
      .then(
        response => this.setState({ userInfo: { ...response.data, id } }),
        () => console.log(this.state.userInfo)
      );
  }


  render() {
    let userInfoList= this.state.userInfo.map((elem,i)=>{
      return(
        <div> name={elem.name}
        id={elem.id}</div>
      )
    })

    console.log(this.state.userInfo);
    return (

      <div>
      {/* <p>{this.state.userInfo}</p> */}
       {/* <div >{userInfoList}</div>
        <ProfileCard profilePic={this.state.userInfo} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: `userInfo` is an object, `.map()` is only used in array

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry for not clarifying I'm just trying to show the data to the page.

Comment: You are initializing userInfo as object`{}`, instead initialize as array `[]`. may be after ajax request its changing to array. But till the execution of `componentDidMount`, `render` is already executed. so its throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what youre trying to do.

First you should change userInfo to an empty array instead of an empty object as others have stated.

Next since you are making an async api call you should use a ternary expression in your render method, because currently React will just render the empty object without waiting for the api call to complete. I would get rid of the userInfoList variable and refactor your code to the following:

```
RenderProfile = (props) => (
 <div>
{props.elem.name}
</div> 
)

{ this.state.userInfo 

 ? this.state.userInfo.map(elem => < this.RenderProfile id={elem.id} elem={elem} /> )

 : null 
}
```

Let me know if it worked for you.